# Python threading and semaphore

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a python class let's call it AClass and another one MyThread which extends Thread. And in that AClass I make 2 objects of the class MyThread and I also have a semaphore which I give it as a parameter to the constructor of the MyThread class. My question is if I modify the semaphore in one MyThread object will the other MyThread object see the difference? Ex:

```
class AClasss:

     def function: 
          semafor = threading.Semaphore(value=maxconnections)
          thread1 = Mythread(semafor)
          thread2 = Mythread(semafor)
          thread1.start()
          thread1.join()
          thread2.start()
          thread2.join()

 class MyThread(Thread):
     def __init__(self,semaphore):
         self.semaphore = semaphore
     def run():
        semaphore.acquire()
        "Do something here" 
        semaphore.release()
```

So does thread1 see the changes to the semaphore that thread2 does and vice versa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the purpose of semaphores, they allow you to safely synchronize concurrent processes.

Keep in mind that threads in Python won't *really* get you concurrency unless you're releasing the GIL (doing IO, calling libraries and so on).  If that's what you're going for, you might want to consider the `multiprocessing` library.

Comment: great thanks, I though it was so but I wanted to be sure before staring coding.